# Neo4j loading csv for a very long time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, load-csv

Hi everyone on Stackoverflow,

I have simple query to load csv, but browser takes long time to load and still shows loading sign.

Here is my query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ratings_small.csv" AS line 
WITH line MERGE (u:User{name:line.userId}) 
MERGE (m:Movie {movieId:line.movieId}) 
MERGE (u)-[r:RATED {rating:line.rating}]->(m) 
RETURN u, m, r
```

I don't see mistake in the code..

ratings_small.csv has following columns:

userId  movieId rating  timestamp

1   31  2.5 1260759144

1   1029    3   1260759179

1   1061    3   1260759182

1   1129    2   1260759185

1   1172    4   1260759205

There are 100 004 records.

Kind regards,
Anna

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't have indexes on both :User(name) and :Movie(movieId).

Perform the two following queries and retry your LOAD CSV command, it should then import it in a couple of seconds :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:User) ASSERT u.name IS UNIQUE;
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (m:Movie) ASSERT m.moveId IS UNIQUE;
```

Secondly, I suppose users rate a movie only once, so the MERGE of the relationship is not necessary to happen with the property, you can change your query like this :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ratings_small.csv" AS line 
WITH line MERGE (u:User{name:line.userId}) 
MERGE (m:Movie {movieId:line.movieId}) 
MERGE (u)-[r:RATED]->(m)
SET r.rating = line.rating
RETURN u, m, r
```

To avoid Neo4j to try to process the full CSV in one transaction, you can [specify the batch size of transactional operations](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-setting-the-rate-of-periodic-commits) (to avoid memory issues) like this :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 2000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ratings_small.csv" AS line 
WITH line MERGE (u:User{name:line.userId}) 
MERGE (m:Movie {movieId:line.movieId}) 
MERGE (u)-[r:RATED]->(m)
SET r.rating = line.rating
RETURN u, m, r
```

Lastly, I doubt you have any application or even the Neo4j browser that can visualise everything at once, so I would not return anything from the LOAD CSV query :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 2000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ratings_small.csv" AS line 
WITH line MERGE (u:User{name:line.userId}) 
MERGE (m:Movie {movieId:line.movieId}) 
MERGE (u)-[r:RATED]->(m)
SET r.rating = line.rating
```

Comment: Thank you I added constraints, now I have this error: Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed - java heap space

Comment: I set as follows: dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=5G
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=5G

Comment: dbms.memory.pagecache.size=2G

Comment: The NODES (:Movie, :User) are loaded Ok one by one.  Now I run the query: -------> USING PERIODIC COMMIT 2000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ratings_small.csv" AS line WITH line MATCH (u:User{userId:line.userId}), (m:Movie{movieId:line.movieId}) CREATE (u)-[r:RATED ]->(m) SET r.rating = line.rating  ------> It outputs: Executing queries that use periodic commits in an open transaction is not possible

Comment: Remove the `WITH line`

Comment: Thank you. It says: The query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns